# Doctrine 2 - Joined entity is still a proxy and generating two queries after request

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, doctrine

```
$news = \DB::getEntityManager()->createQueryBuilder()
    ->select('n')
    ->from('Model\News', 'n')
    ->join('n.category', 'c')
    ->join('n.locales', 'l')
    ->where('l.language = :lang AND n.id = :id AND n.published = 1')
    ->setParameter('id', $news_id)
    ->setParameter('lang', $lang)
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();

$news->category->getName();
```

This code is generating TWO queries instead of ONE. **Why?**

After getting my `$news` entity, the `category` property is still a Doctrine proxy class (`Application\Proxies\__CG__\Model\News\Category`). Instance of `\Model\News\Category` will be loaded only after getting some of the category data (with, for example, `$news->category->getName()`) and it's generating **additional** SQL query.

How to make Doctrine to download `\Model\News` and related to it `\Model\News\Category` with only one query?

Below is a configuration for `category` field from `\Model\News` with annotations:

```
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Model\News\Category", inversedBy="news", fetch="EAGER")
 */
public $category;
```

As You can see... `EAGER` is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your first line to `->select('n, c')` so that Doctrine will hydrate both your News and Category entities.

Comment: Is it working only when Doctrine cache is set to other than `ArrayCache`?